# UICollectionViewCell anchor/constraint schoolboy error

Tags: swift, uicollectionviewcell

I have a layout issue with an extra large label (that I need truncated) and a UISwitch within a UIStackView. The UI rendering is clearly not correct, see the screenshot https://www.dropbox.com/s/ankoovfh874kgy7/AlignmentTruncation.jpg

Obviously it is just too late in the evening and I have been staring at this too long. If anyone can help me with this schoolboy error, I would be grateful.

Dev environment Xcode 10.2 (10E125), macOS Mojave 10.14.5 Beta.

Thanks

Mike

```
class SwitchableOptionCell : UICollectionViewCell {

    let switchView : UISwitch = {
        let sv = UISwitch()
        return sv
    }()

    let labelView : UILabel = {
        let lv = UILabel()
        lv.backgroundColor = .red
        lv.text = "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog"
        lv.lineBreakMode = .byTruncatingTail
        return lv
    }()

    override init(frame : CGRect)
    {
        super.init(frame : frame)

        let sv = UIStackView(arrangedSubviews: [labelView, switchView])
        sv.spacing = 12
        sv.alignment = .center

        addSubview(sv)

        sv.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

        sv.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.topAnchor).isActive = true
        sv.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo : self.leadingAnchor, constant: 16).isActive = true
        sv.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo : self.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
        sv.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo : self.trailingAnchor, constant: -16).isActive = true
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder : NSCoder)
    {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
}
```

Comment: First, why use a collection view and not a table view for this? Second, why use a stack view and not just add the views to the cell yourself? For this layout, those two together are overkill.

Answer (score 0):

just try to change
        sv.alignment = .center
to
        sv.alignment = .fill
or
        sv.alignment = .fillProportionaly

Issue may be related to uiswitch. He doesn`t know actual width he has. So you can try to create some container for uiswitch with width constraint

Comment: Thanks, sv.alignment = .fill makes no difference and there is no UIStackView.Alignment.fillProportionally enum

Comment: And just as an update, two UILabel has the expected StackView layout behaviour, but a UILabel and UISwitch results in the peculiar layout.  If I shorten the label text, the UILabel and UISwitch also have the expected layout

Comment: Oh, i mean UIStackView.Distribution.fillProportionally.

Ok, try container then :)

Comment: Nope,                
        
        sv.alignment = .fill
        sv.distribution = .fillProportionally
        
Same layout issue.

Comment: Try do like this http://prntscr.com/n6khap
Also need to center switch in container

Comment: I write programmatically, not using the interface builder UI, but yes but is the same sort of truncation issue. Exactly what I observe is: https://www.dropbox.com/s/ankoovfh874kgy7/AllignmentTruncation.jpg

Comment: Thanks, just to be clear, the layout I put in the screenshot is the observed behaviour, not the wanted nor expected behaviour. I am missing something, and I am not sure what it is